# Cosine rule to find a side of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to ask you for help for the following problem:

The sides of a $\triangle ABC$ are $BC=2,AB=5,AC=\sqrt{22}$ and point $D$ lies on $AC$, such that $BD=3$. Find $CD$.

> $CD=\dfrac{\sqrt{22}}{2}$

[image]

I have just studied the Cosine rule and I think I am supposed to use it. I don't see how, though. To find $CD$ we can use the Cosine rule in $\triangle BCD:CD^2=BC^2+BD^2-2.BC.BD.\cos\measuredangle CBD$ but I don't see how to find $\cos\measuredangle CBD$. I also found $\cos\gamma=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=\dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{22}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{22}}{88}.$

Comment: See Stewart's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the cosine rule on triangle ACB to find $\measuredangle ACB$.

Then use the cosine rule on triangle BCD to find the length of $CD$.

Comment: Thank you. I have already found that $\cos\gamma=\dfrac{\sqrt{22}}{88}$ (see the text below the picture). How to use the Cosine rule on triangle BCD to find the length of $CD$?

Comment: Knowing that $\cos(\gamma)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{22}}$ you can then use the Cosine rule on $\triangle CDB$ again to get $DB$

Comment: Assuming $\gamma = \measuredangle ACB$. This this is the same as angle $\measuredangle DCB$ because $D$ lies on $AC$, and $AC$ is a straight line. You also forgot to draw on the diagram that $BD = 3$, which you were told in the question. Then the cosine rule with $\measuredangle DCB$ says that...

Comment: @Eagertolearnmath you should get a quadratic in $x$. Just solve for that.

Comment: Yes, I got a quadratic in $x$ and solve it. $CD=\dfrac{\sqrt{22}}{2}$. Thank you!